# get text of dynamically generated dropdowns onchange and reuse function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onchange

I have the following elements, each one is the id of a select element which will have a dynamically generated dropdown list:

```
const year = document.getElementById('year');
const brand = document.getElementById('brand');
const version = document.getElementById('version');
const model = document.getElementById('model');
```

I have the following handle function which I would like to reuse for every single one of them:

```
function handleChange() {
    let selected = year.options[year.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selected);
}

year.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
```

So far that is working but idk how to make handleChange() take the id of the SELECT element. I tried the following code but it's not correct.

```
function handleChange(e) {
    let id = e.target.id;
    let selected = id.options[id.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log(selected);
}
```

I'm trying to stay away from JQuery on this one.

Comment: `this` should refer to the element already, no need to go looking for stuff by id. But if you are explicitly accessing the _id_, that id course doesn’t have any `options` property, it is pure text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `this` inside the change event callback function, in your case the `handleChange` function.

This is how should be your code:

```
function handleChange() {
  let selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(selected);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const year = document.getElementById('year');

year.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange() {
  let selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(selected);
}
```

```html
<select id="year">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: works perfectly! I was quite convinced I needed to get the id of the element for this to work...

Comment: @szter Why would you get the `id`? If you get it you need to fetch back the element with `getElementById()` again, this is too far complicated.